# Pandas DataFrame: Alias for Index column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, alias

I would like to speed up operations on a `DataFrame` by applying an `Index` during load (`read_sql`). But I do not want to change big parts of the code *from a reasonable variable name* to a non-specific variable name `index`. Lets explain this on an example:

Lets say I have DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql=QRY, con=connection)

|  Name  | Grade |   |   |   |
|--------|-------|---|---|---|
| Peter  | 2     |   |   |   |
| Albert | 1     |   |   |   |
| Lea    | 1     |   |   |   |
```

so I can nicely access the column later on using `df.Name`:

```
|  Name  |
|--------|
| Peter  |
| Albert | 
| Lea    |
```

but now applying an `index_col`

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql=QRY, con=connection, index_col='Name')

|  Index | Grade |   |   |   |
|--------|-------|---|---|---|
| Peter  | 2     |   |   |   |
| Albert | 1     |   |   |   |
| Lea    | 1     |   |   |   |
```

it is no more possible to access the variable using `df.Name`. I could access it using `df.index`, but this would lower the code quality enormously. Is it possible to link the `Index` to the orignal `index_col`? And is there a solution for `MultiIndex` as well (bonus)?

Comment: do you want `.reset_index()`?

Comment: @ansev `.reset_index()` removes the index. I want to keep it as an Index and be able to use it with the original name `Name`.

Comment: `df['Name'] = df.index.to_series()` or `df['Name_col'] = df.index.to_series()`

Comment: or use `pd.read_csv` with out index_col and then use `df.set_index('Name',drop=False)`